# Compare Strings Loop Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, hash

I am trying to create a loop that compares strings from a list I have already created. The list is of passwords, and the same passwords hashed with md5. I have a function that does the hashing, and another that prints out the list of both passwords. The new function "findmd5" is supposed to compare each md5 encrypted value of the password list with the encrypted string that is passed in. "pass2check" is a predetermined string that I am trying to use in the loop, its md5 value should return the password "football". The code in my new function is very incomplete because I am lost on the next steps to take..

```
import hashlib
passwordlist = ["password","123456","12345678","1234","qwerty","12345",
"baseball","football","letmein","monkey","abc123","mustang","michael"]

def makemd5(key_string):

    new_key_string = key_string.encode('utf-8')

    return (hashlib.md5 ( new_key_string ).hexdigest())

def createmd5list(passwordlist):

    for passlist in passwordlist:
        hashlist = makemd5(passlist)
        print (passlist,",",hashlist)

def findmd5(pass2check):

    for line in open(passwordlist + hashlist): 
        if pass2check in line:
            print(True)
        else:
            print(False)


def main():

    pass2check = "37b4e2d82900d5e94b8da524fbeb33c0"



main ()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Comment: In particular, your code produces no output and no errors.  "I am lost" is not a problem specification; rather, it suggests that you need a resource other than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Your main program doesn't call *any* of your functions.  How do you know the other ones work?  What data does findmd5 need from them?  We really don't have a way to give you StackOverflow-level help without doing the work *you're* supposed to put into your posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this ():

```
import hashlib
passwordlist = ["password","123456","12345678","1234","qwerty","12345",
"baseball","football","letmein","monkey","abc123","mustang","michael"]

def listOfHashs():
    return [hashlib.md5(item.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest() for item in passwordlist]

def main():
    pass2check = "37b4e2d82900d5e94b8da524fbeb33c0"
    index = listOfHashs().index(pass2check)
    print(passwordlist[index] if index >= 0 else "Hash not found !")

main()
```

in this version i've tried to modify your code:

```
import hashlib
passwordlist = ["password","123456","12345678","1234","qwerty","12345",
"baseball","football","letmein","monkey","abc123","mustang","michael"]

def makemd5(key_string):
    new_key_string = key_string.encode('utf-8')
    return (hashlib.md5 ( new_key_string ).hexdigest())

def createmd5list(passwordlist):
    hashlist = []
    for passlist in passwordlist:
        hashlist += [makemd5(passlist)]
    return hashlist

def findmd5(pass2check):
    for index, line in enumerate(createmd5list(passwordlist)): 
        if pass2check in line:
            return index
    return -1


def main():
    pass2check = "37b4e2d82900d5e94b8da524fbeb33c0"
    index = findmd5(pass2check)
    if index >= 0:
        print passwordlist[index]
    else:
        print "Hash not found !"

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to create the list of hashed passwords. Instead, you build the digest and filter inside the list comprehension and the final list only contains the valid solutions.

Reworking your own code, it could look like

```
import hashlib
passwordlist = ["password","123456","12345678","1234","qwerty","12345",
    "baseball","football","letmein","monkey","abc123","mustang","michael"]

def findmd5(pass2check):
    result = [password for password in passwordlist 
              if hashlib.md5(password).hexdigest() == pass2check
             ]
    if len(result):
        print("The answer is")
        for password in result:
            print(password)
    else:
        print("Password not found")

def main():

    pass2check = "37b4e2d82900d5e94b8da524fbeb33c0"
    findmd5(pass2check)


main ()
```

This will print all the valid solutions